# Using Kylin without HDFS and HBase

Tags: database, hbase, hdfs, kylin

is it possible to connect Apache Kylin without other databases like Hbase (plus HDFS) in general? So you can store raw data and the cube metadata somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

I think you coulde use Apache Hive using managed native tables
([Hive storage handlers](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/StorageHandlers))
Hive could connect over ODBC driver to MySQL for example

Answer (score -1):

To use Kylin ,HDFS is mandatatory .Raw data as well as Cube data both will be stored in HDFS.

If you want to support other nosql datastore like cassandra ,you can consider other framework ,FiloDB